# Whats d best way to Tell user about ios App update?

Tags: ios, web-services

If i am making an client/server ios App, and i release a new version of that app on App store + other stores on internet. Then, how to manage to tell user to update the app ???
I searched on this...and i got two ways
1. To have web service tht returns current version of app and inform user to update it.
2. To check the URL of app on itunes and it returns info from which we cn get version (doubtful on this)
Because, if there is such an URL, we will have to write the URL address in code before uploading...Pls guide on this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel! What you are looking for is [iVersion by nicklockwood](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion).

Comment: Have you used it, is it reliable. What are the limitations of this...??? ...they haven't written in their Reademe about this.

Comment: I used it yes and works since a long time. I don't know any limitations, because this kind of application doesn't have much functionality.

Comment: And suppose they start charging for it or suddenly shut there service. then your app will die for update RIGHT ????

Comment: Did you had a look at the link? That is just an open source project which is based on the iTunes search API.

Comment: yeah...i saw it ...bt hot other way of doing it ...i know how to get it done by itunes url. And would like to have my mechanism for such use case. In between, thanks for your kind help....